# How can I pass paramters wenn I use onGenerateRoute?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I try to preload the products from the App Store and pass them to initalRoute. The problem is that I work with onGenerateRoute and initialRoute and its not possible to pass the products to it.

```
    Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
      FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
    
      // Get Products
      final bool available = await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable();
      if (available) {
        Set<String> ids = <String>{
          product1Months,
        };
        ProductDetailsResponse response =
            await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(ids);
    
        products =
            response.productDetails.map((e) => PurchasableProduct(e)).toList();
      }
    
      runApp(Phoenix(child: MyApp(products)));
     }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
    
      final List<PurchasableProduct> products;
    
      const MyApp(this.mappedJson, this.initialUser, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
       @override
        _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
       }
    
   class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
    
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    
       return MaterialApp(
    
       initialRoute: '/',
       onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,

...
```

then I have a Routegenerator:

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    // Getting arguments passed in while calling Navigator.pushNamed
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => AuthenticationWrapper(index: args));
...
```

How can I use the products which I preload in the main in the AuthenticationWrapper? Or is there another way for preloading the products?

Comment: use `arguments` parameter when calling `pushNamed` - for more read [pushNamed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushNamed.html) official docs

Comment: thanks but I dont want to push. I want to pass the preloaded products list to initalroute.

Comment: so pass your products to `RouteGenerator` class in the constructor or any other way so that you can access your products when `generateRoute` is called

Comment: I dont know how to do that because its static.

Comment: thanks but i solved it with provider